# IOS editor bug. archivedData renamed

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

Please help me! I am stuck in a loop and can't find my way out. I am trying to learn IOS programming for work so I thought I would start with their tutorial app the Meal list application. I am at the part where you are supposed to start saving persistent data and now the editor has me stuck in a never ending loop. I have a line of code...

```
let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
```

That gives me a warning that says...

> 'archiveRootObject(_:toFile:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use
>   +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

OK, so I change the line of code to...

```
let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(meals)
```

Which then gives me the warning...

> 'archivedDataWithRootObject' has been renamed to
>   'archivedData(withRootObject:)'

OK, so I change the line of code to...

```
let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meals)
```

Which tells me...

> 'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use
>   +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

OK... So... archivedData was deprecated and I have to use archivedDataWithRootObject, but using archivedDataWithRootObject has been renamed to archivedData, but archivedData is deprecated so use archivedDataWithRootObject which is renamed to archivedData which is deprecated... ad infinitum.

I have tried looking on the developer docs but they just tell me the same thing, one is deprecated, with no links or anything and searching google just gives me a bunch of pages showing me the syntax of using any of them. I am still really new to IOS programming and have no idea how to get out of this endless loop of deprecated to renamed to deprecated to...

Please help, I am lost and not sure how to continue. Thank you.

Comment: Another question to ask is why use `NSKeyedArchiver` at all in Swift? Why not use modern Swift APIs based around `Codable`?

Comment: The 2 above comments are literally trash , first deprecation should be avoided anyway in code , second the answer is very related to the zone of the question

Comment: @matt  So you're suggestion for a completely new programmer to a language is to ignore warning and don't ask questions? Thank you, that's helpful. I DON'T know IOS programming.

Comment: What I’m saying is don’t  call it a bug and don’t vent. Just ask.

Comment: I understand and I apologize, I just didn't know how else to describe it. The editor is of no help since it just sends me in a loop and the docs are extremely non helpful to a completely new IOS developer. I didn't quite understand the whole :requireingSecureCoding:error: piece of the whole thing, so it just looks like a bug to a complete newbie, where you get stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am following [the same example you are trying to do](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1), and I figured out how to update the methods for storing and retrieving values in iOS 12, this should help you:

```
//MARK: Private Methods
private func saveMeals() {

    let fullPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("meals")

    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meals, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        try data.write(to: fullPath)
        os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } catch {
        os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]? {
    let fullPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("meals")
    if let nsData = NSData(contentsOf: fullPath) {
        do {

            let data = Data(referencing:nsData)

            if let loadedMeals = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? Array<Meal> {
                return loadedMeals
            }
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't read file.")
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Also you will find that you need to update ViewDidLoad as this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    let savedMeals = loadMeals()

    if savedMeals?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
        meals = savedMeals ?? [Meal]()
    } else {
        loadSampleMeals()
    }

}
```

I hope this helps, for me the app is now working, storing and retrieving data.

FYI: This doesn't work with Xcode 11 beta and iOS 13 is should work with anything before those versions.

Answer (score 5):

A general solution for iOS 12 would be:

```
class SettingsArchiver {
    static func setData(_ value: Any, key: String) {
        let ud = UserDefaults.standard
        let archivedPool = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        ud.set(archivedPool, forKey: key)
    }

    static func getData<T>(key: String) -> T? {
        let ud = UserDefaults.standard
        if let val = ud.value(forKey: key) as? Data,
            let obj = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(val) as? T {
            return obj
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
try {
   let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:meals,requiringSecureCoding:true)
   try data.write(to:fullPath)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Here in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/2962880-archiveddata) it's IOS 11+

Comment: What about the "toFile" part of the original call that is in their tutorial app? Does it all go to the same place now? I had to add static members to my Meal class of...
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirecory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

Comment: yes but it's deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/1410621-archiverootobject , you need to use the secure one in answer and write the returned data to the file

Comment: So I still have to write the data to a file after I run the archivedData function? I have no idea how to do that. Their tutorial is obviously outdated and tells you to use deprecated methods that are supposed to write to file automatically

Comment: Check my answer buddy.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, the answer directly addressing your question is to use the ArchiveURL defined in your Meal.swift data model (think MVC pattern) and reimplement the `saveMeals()` function in your MealTableViewController.swift controller using the recommended replacement to the deprecated `archiveRootObject` method this way:

```
private func saveMeals(){
    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meals, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try data.write(to: Meal.ArchiveURL)
    }
    catch {
        print("Couldn't save to file")
    }
}
```

Although this answer is a little late :-) I hope it helps whomever may come across this issue.

Comment: Also, you will have to add 'NSSecureCoding' to your Meal class declaration and also the following varible declaration: 'static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true'